# How do I test a method (using unittest) that closes a PIL image?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-imaging-library, python-unittest

I have a method (`close()`) that's part of my class (`Img`) that goes like this:

```
    def close(self):
        Image.Image.close(self.image)
```

I've been struggling to find a way to test this method with the **unittest** package because it doesn't return anything and I don't know if there's a way to actually check if an image is closed or not.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: As you probably don't want to test the functionality of PIL, the only thing you can test here is to check that `Image.Image.close` is called (by mocking it).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [unittest.mock.patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch) method to mock `PIL` package and `Image.Image.close` method. After calling your `img.close()` method, you can use [assert_called_once_with(*args, **kwargs)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_called_once_with) to check `Image.Image.close` method is called or not.

E.g.

`img.py`:

```py
from PIL import Image


class Img:
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = '123'

    def close(self):
        Image.Image.close(self.image)
```

`test_img.py`:

```py
import unittest
from unittest import mock
from img import Img


class TestImg(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('img.Image')
    def test_close(self, mock_Image):
        my_img = Img()
        my_img.close()
        mock_Image.Image.close.assert_called_once_with('123')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

unit test result with coverage report:

```
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
Name                                     Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
----------------------------------------------------------------------
src/stackoverflow/63132966/img.py            6      0   100%
src/stackoverflow/63132966/test_img.py      10      0   100%
----------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                       16      0   100%
```